# is it possible to detect if a element has validate attributes like ng-maxwidth?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a central angular directive to watch validation rules like ng-maxlength, ... - That works fine, but in my current solution I have a lot of watchers and I try to reduce them by looking if the attribute is really set in der HTML Element.

form.element**.required**  works easy, but the others?

Regards klaus

Comment: Your central directive has access to an "Attrs" property that has all the attributes for the element, right? You could check there.

Comment: Thanks, you are right "attr" was the solution.